# Vertically wrapping a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the content of div vertically wrap on overflow thus causing it to stretch horizontally instead of vertically.

Is there a way to do this in CSS or maybe javascript library that helps achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a demo in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Are you saying that you never want to see a vertical scroll but simply an increasingly long horizontal scroll?

Comment: @Terry Yes, instead of vertically scrolling I would like the  div to horizontally expand in size.

Comment: @Fredy At the moment no, I'm still trying to see if it's possible.

Comment: Have you seen a site that does this somewhere already?? If so, maybe we could break it down and come up with your solution.

Comment: I see you have an answer. If that doesn't work, I'm wondering if, when the content becomes bigger than the window, you could simply keep increasing the css width. Just a thought; I've never tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question using the Isotope Jquery plugin.

Code:

```
$container.isotope({ 
    layoutMode: 'fitColumns',
    resizable: true
 });​
```

Here's a link to the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzQPM/

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`: http://jsfiddle.net/EH5uy/

Alternatively you can do `display: inline`, but you won't be able to do margins properly